# std::transform_reduce when the initial value is a vector

Tags: c++, c++17

I was trying to figure out how to use std::transform_reduce when my initial value is a vector. Here is an example code of what I was essentially trying to do.

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <locale>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

vector<double> transf(double x)
{
    vector<double> a={1,2,3,4};

    return a;
}

vector<double> reduc(vector<double> &a, vector<double> &b)
{
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++) a[i]+=b[i];
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> sum(4,0);
    vector<double> it(4,0);

    transform_reduce(it.cbegin(),it.cend(),sum,reduc,transf);

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) cout<<sum[i]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This fails since the function `transf` returns an rvalue which cannot be converted to a non const lvalue for `reduc` arguments. One option would be to use const refernces and create a temporary vector inside `reduc` to store the sum and return that but i would rather not do extra allocation.

Below is a raw pointer version of what I was trying to do. Is there any way to do the same with vectors?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <locale>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

double* transf(double x)
{
    double *a=new double[4];
    a[0]=1;a[1]=2;a[2]=3;a[3]=4;

    return a;
}

double* reduc(double* a, double* b)
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) a[i]+=b[i];
    delete[] b;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    double *sum=new double[4]; for(int i=0;i<4;i++) sum[i]=0;
    vector<double> it(100000000,0);

    transform_reduce(it.cbegin(),it.cend(),sum,reduc,transf);

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) cout<<sum[i]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have found this relevant link: [Can you modify temporary intermediate values from transform step in std::transform_reduce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68293954/can-you-modify-temporary-intermediate-values-from-transform-step-in-stdtransfo). But I don't know if it is memory safe. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you are much better off writing your own version of `transform_reduce`, it's like 5 lines.

Comment: You should mind the semantics of your functions. For example, your `reduc` *modifies* its first argument outside the function, and then returns a *new copy* of that vector. If you wrote the interface of the function to make intuitive sense, making use of const and/or rvalue references, you would not need to ask this question at all - everything would work.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes can you elaborate a little bit on what you mean? I don't really understand what you mean by `reduc` modifiying outside the function. If possible ca you show me a code snippet? Thanks.

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce) *"The behavior is undefined if reduce, or transform modifies any element or invalidates any iterator in the input ranges, including their end iterators."* you (try to) modify lhs in `reduc`.

Comment: @codeenjoyer `reduc` takes its arguments by non-const reference, which means all modifications to the arguments inside the function (the `+=` line) have side effects on its arguments at the call site. `vector<double> a = transf(0), b = transf(0), c = reduc(a, b);` would result in `a == {2,4,6,8}`

Answer (score 0):

(Edited due to useful comment.)

I would suggest for you to use the function output and passing both vectors as const ref, e.g.:

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <locale>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

vector<double> transf(double)
{
    vector<double> a={1,2,3,4};

    return a;
}

vector<double> reduc(const vector<double>& a, const vector<double>& b)
{
    vector<double> v;
    for(size_t i=0;i<a.size();i++)
        v.push_back(a[i]+b[i]);
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> sum(4,0);
    vector<double> it(4,0);

    vector<double> result = transform_reduce(it.cbegin(),it.cend(),sum,reduc,transf);

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        cout<<result[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Result:
4
8
12
16

Comment: The standard library doesn't move the vectors into the functions, so each vector will be copied once or twice, this is very bad.